# QT Compile on Linux: Cross Compilation failed with mxe / mingw / Linux, Debian

Tags: c++, linux, qt, mingw32, mxe

I cannot compile the Windows Wallet, it shows me everytime this Error:
What have I missed here?
I am Using Debian.

Source Code: https://github.com/rat4/blackcoin

Content of compile-gtc.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
MXE_INCLUDE_PATH=/mnt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include
MXE_LIB_PATH=/mnt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib

i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 \
    BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mt \
    BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX=_win32-mt \
    BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH=$MXE_INCLUDE_PATH/boost \
    BOOST_LIB_PATH=$MXE_LIB_PATH \
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=$MXE_INCLUDE_PATH/openssl \
    OPENSSL_LIB_PATH=$MXE_LIB_PATH \
    BDB_INCLUDE_PATH=$MXE_INCLUDE_PATH \
    BDB_LIB_PATH=$MXE_LIB_PATH \
    MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH=$MXE_INCLUDE_PATH \
    MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH=$MXE_LIB_PATH \
    QMAKE_LRELEASE=/mnt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin/lrelease blackcoin-qt.pro

make -f Makefile.Release
```

After some minutes i started ./compile-gtc.sh I got this Error:

> /mnt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/libdb_cxx.a(os_pid.o):os_pid.c:(.text+0x25):
>   undefined reference to `pthread_self' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status Makefile.Release:427: recipe for target
>   'release/blackcoin-qt.exe' failed make: *** [release/blackcoin-qt.exe]
>   Error 1

Thank you,

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) asking us to browse your code base is not such an example.

Comment: The Source is not the Problem, it works. It will be mxe which have Problems

Comment: Yup, so hopefully putting together an MCVE will be pretty easy. The fact is that I usually find my solution as I'm setting up the MCVE. Maybe the same will be true for you?

Comment: Okay but what do u need exactly for MCVE? I'm very new here and don't now what you expect to get with MCVE. Thanks.

Comment: I'd personally start with a "Hello World!" example that links in nothing but the Windows Wallet.

Comment: Hey, I have fixed this Error now, It seems that the .pro File is wrong, but it won't compile i got now: net.cpp:(.text+0x5100): undefined reference to `freeUPNPDevlist'

Comment: Great work! I think I'd close this, make a MCVE demonstrating the "freeUPNPDevlist", then open a new question with that example. If you comment here with the question link I'll come try to help answer.